# How do I disable pinch zoom on a HTML page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

I need to be able to disable pinch to zoom on a HTML web page but I have not been able to work out how to do it yet. I have tried a bunch of different solutions to no avail. I hope you can help. Some of the solutions I have tried include...

1.

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <title>Wow</title>
</head>
```

2. 

```
<head>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener("gesturestart", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.style.zoom = 0.99;
        });
        document.addEventListener("gesturechange", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.style.zoom = 0.99;
        });
        document.addEventListener("gestureend", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            document.body.style.zoom = 1;
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

3. 

```
body {
    touch-action: none;
}
```

I hope you can help.